# emoji look up table and algorithm

Tags: android, algorithm, emoji

I am trying to build an android app that the user can enter a string, and a list emoji related to that string would show up. (Just like Venmo app) For example:

case 1: User enters "pizz", and in the list there would be "", note that the users enter "pizz", not pizza!
case 2: User enters "rabb", and in the list there would be "" and "", note that the users enter "rabb", not rabbit!

What would be a good data structure and algorithm for this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A **trie** is what your looking for. From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie)

> A trie, also called digital tree and sometimes radix tree or *prefix tree* (as they can be **searched by prefixes**), is a kind of search tree—an ordered tree data structure ...

A trie is similar to a `HashMap<K,V>`, you can perform a lookup with keys and get a value. The difference is that you can also search by *prefix*. Given a prefix, it will find all the key-value pairs in the structure that have that prefix. It's basically *the* data structure  for generating search suggestions.

General Idea:

```
Trie<String, String> t = new Trie<String, String>();
t.insert("pizza", "");
t.insert("rabbit1", "");
t.insert("rabbit2", "");
// then later...
t.findByPrefix("rabb"); // [,]
```

Unfortunately, tries are too generic and are not present in any popular data structure libraries (like Java Collections Framework or Google Guava, for example). You'd have to implement one yourself or find an existing implementation and modify it.
I'd recommend:

1. Learning the theory. Watch this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zIjfhVPRZCg). There are many more on YouTube that will teach you the basics. You can also search google for "N-way trie" and read notes about it.
2. Taking this class `TrieST` and modifying it. It's very similar (or already perfect) for what you need: http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/52trie/TrieST.java.html see specifically the`keysWithPrefix` method.